# MongoDB Issue on long index creation via PyMongo

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, database, python, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm connecting remotely to a MongoDB standalone instance and in my python script am creating/ensuring indexes in the background before doing a `bulk_update()` operation.

The collection is 90+Million documents and the index creation (if not existing before) takes 20-30 minutes, which is not the issue.
I keep track of it on the `mongod.log` remotely and after each successful build, the script hangs on the local side whereas the server errors with

`Error sending response to client: SocketException: Connection timed out. Ending connection from <SERVER IP>`

Outside of increasing the connection timeouts to 30-60min, is there any way to ensure I keep the connection to mongo without it stalling my script?

**Versions:**

*Local*
Python: 3.6
PyMongo: 3.8.0
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

*Remote*
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Mongo: 4.0.6-3

Comment: Do you still get the error if you increase the timeout?

Comment: I have tried the various MongoClient options listed [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) but they don't seem to help as the one I figured as the most relevant `socketTimeoutMS` defaults to no timeout.
Perhaps I'm dealing with native Linux and Windows socket timeouts?

Comment: The default TCP timeouts are measured in _hours_. Look for a firewall or NAT device that might be interrupting your connection.

Comment: Please post TEXT results to pastebin.com (or similar service) from A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for your local instance and the REMOTE MONGODB instance for analysis AND B) your python script AND C) last 100 lines of mongod.log.